# How to skip symbols in the end of the regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have the next regular expression:

```
const string pattern        = "(\\w)</span>";
const string replace        = "$1&nbsp;</span>";
var rgx                     = new Regex(pattern);
```

So, it matches everything that finishes with  and has a symbol right in front of it.
I want to make it match the same phrases except for the once that have a punctuation mark in the end of it

Example:

```
 Mom</span>, is awesome ....
```

I don't want it to match also:

```
Adventure is the best</span>. So now we keep on doin it ...
```

I tried :

```
const string pattern        = "(\\w)</span>[^\\W]$";
const string pattern        = "(\\w)</span>(^\\W)$";
```

but it didn't work at all.

THE RESULT I AM LOOKING FOR:
if there is a phrase :

```
Mom</span>, Dad
```

as part of the html text I do NOT want to match it, because I dont want to add space in front of the comma - > Mom , Dad . I want it to stay Mom, Dad after being parsed.

BUT if i had :

```
Mom</span>and Dad (After parsing it comes like : Momand Dad)
```

I to add a space before "and" so it can turn into "Mom and Dad" after being parsed.

I HOPE that now you can get an idea what  I am trying to do!

Comment: don't use regex to parse html.. (Try html agility pack)

Comment: I am actualy using exactly the html agility pack.When I assign the html content to a string I need to edit it a little bit.This is why I am using regex's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const string pattern  = "(\\w)</span>(?![.])";
```

If there might be some spaces before the punctuation, you can try this:

```
const string pattern  = "(\\w)</span>(?!\s*[.])";
```

Comment: Can you tell me What exactly the group (?![.]) does?

Can I add this : (\\w)</span>(?!([.]|[,]|[:])) ? So I can skip the comma and the double comma ?

Comment: @mathinvalidnik that's called `Lookahead`, you can search for `Lookahead`, `Lookbehind` and `Look-around` in regex. If you want to add more characters, try `(?![.,:])`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
    const string pattern        = "(\\w)</span>[^,.]";
```

This [^,.] means any one character different from: , or .

You could expand to [^,.;:] or anything else you need and perhaps you could use [^,.] a quantifier like * or + to specify that there may be more than one punctuation character.

Comment: where did the </span> go?

Comment: My bad on code indentation, the editor ate up the </span> as it is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I tried something but i could not get any direct idea. Just sharing some different method.
    Have two pattern one with punctuation and another without punctuation

    Without punctuation pattern:
        const string pattern = "(\\w)</span>([^\.\,]+)$"; (u replace with space)
    Another one with punctuation pattern:
        const string pattern = "(\\w)</span>[\,\.\\w]+$"; (u replace without space)


In both pattern add the punctuations you want at end eg. ([^\:\;]+)$
```

Comment: i am not able to understand your requirement, please tell what output exactly you want and what output you are now getting. with eg